# How many Subsets does a Null set has? 2 or 1

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image: The Question asked is given here]

How can this Question's answer be 2? If it was the number of elements for the set {Φ} I would have gone with 2, But how is the Answer this question be 2?

Comment: use mathjax instead of images

Comment: The correct answer is $1{}{}{}{}{}{}$.

Comment: $\emptyset$ has one subset. $\{\emptyset\}$ has two subsets.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews; what are the two subsets of $\{\emptyset\}$?

Comment: @JMP $\emptyset$ (since empty set is always a subset of any set) and $\{\emptyset\}$ (since the whole set is also always a subset). There are no others in this special case. If we consider the set $E=\{\ddot{\smile}\}$ then it also has two subsets: $\emptyset$ and $\{\ddot{\smile}\}$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo; what's the difference between $\{\}$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ then?

Comment: $\{\}$ is just another notation for $\emptyset$ (though I have to admit, the last time I saw that notation was in middle school). $\{\emptyset\}$ on the other hand is a set which contains one element. Sure, this element is itself a set, and in fact is the empty set $\emptyset$; but don't let this confuse you. $\{\emptyset\}$ is a set with one element, so it is not the same thing as $\emptyset$ (which has no elements).

Comment: What is the difference between $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{\{1,2\}\}=\{A\}?$ $A$ has two elements, $1$ and $2.$ $B$ has one element, $A.$ $\emptyset=\{\}$ has zero elements, $\{\emptyset\}$ has one element, $\emptyset.$ Think of it this way: the empty set contains nothing. The empty set is, itself, not nothing, it is a set which contains nothing.

Answer (score 1):

(1) The null set is a subset of every set; so the null set certainly has at least one subset, namely itself.

(2) Now suppose that S is a second subset of the null set. in that case, we have :

$(a)\Large S\subseteq \emptyset$

and

$(b)\Large S\neq \emptyset $

(3) The extensionnality axiom tells us that two sets must differ by at least one element in order to be different. So $(b)$ implies that : either $\emptyset$ has an element that does not belong to $S$ , or $S$ has an element that does not belong to $\emptyset$. But the first option is impossible ( by the definition of the empty set), so only the second remains.

(4) The second option says : there is at least some object $x$ such that $\Large  x\in S$ and $\Large x\notin \emptyset$, meaning ( by &-elimination) that there is at least some object $x$ such that $\Large x\in S$.  But , by $(2.a)$ above , $\Large S\subseteq \emptyset$, which means that all elements of $S$ are also elements of $\emptyset$. This holds in particular for object $x$. So, the second option leads to : $\Large x\in \emptyset$ , another impossibility.

(5) Conclusion : the empty set cannot have any subset in addition to itself; the number of its subsets is $1$.